# Multiple choice question: Choosing the right domain and codomain

Tags: geometry

http://mat.absolutamente.net/recursos/fichas/exames/12ano/funcoes/graf_operac_transform.pdf

It's exercise 16, it's on portuguese but I will translate (I only post the link so you can see the image and the options).

So you have an equilateral triangle, $\Delta ABC$, with perimeter $6$. We have the point $P$ that goes from $B$ to $C$.

$x$ - $\angle BAP$ (angle measure is radians)

$g(x)$ - it's the function that pairs each angle with the length of the segment $AP$

Which is the domain and codomain of the function $g$?

Answer (score 0):

The angle $x$ of the equilateral triangle goes from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{3}$ beacause of the definition of equilateral triangle (every angle is $\frac{\pi}{3}$).
So the domain of the function is $[0,\frac{\pi}{3}]$.
The triangle ha every edge with length 2 (obvious), and it's the maximum length of $AP$ (explainable simply with logic).
You can easily see also that the minimum length of $AP$ is where $AP$ is bisector of the angle $BAC$ (and in an equilateral triangle bisector = height = median).
In this case the angle you form between $AP$ and $BC$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$, so you can easily calcolate with Pythagoras theorem the length of $AP$ (which result to be $\sqrt3$).
So thecodomain results to be $[\sqrt3,2]$.

Comment: Actually Range is $[\sqrt{3},2]$, you could set the codomain to be any interval including the range.